# mongodb best practice to multi-document update (without transaction)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I am working on stock management service for our ecommerce and decided to try out mongodb. In this service, I have to implement a multi-document update.

I know mongodb supports transaction and I tried, but it seems very unstable. It occasionally succeeds, but most of the time it returns this error:`Transaction 1 has been committed.` From what I have googled, the solution is basically to add a retry logic until it works. I figured this is not a good approach. In average it required 10 retries and according to mongodb documents, transactions are more costly compared to other queries. Despite "supporting" transaction, mongodb also suggests not to rely on transaction.

Finally, I decided to use server side locking system(async-lock module) to lock the relevant stocks, while it is being updated. Now this solves my biggest problem, the concurrency issue. I am expecting that the atomicity of the whole update problem is far less, by keeping the update part as simple as possible(unless the server goes down in the middle of the process), but it still is an issue.

Also I dont think its best practice to keep locks on server side.

So I am wondering if there is a right NoSQL approach to solve my transaction problem.

Let me explain my problem in detail:

The core part of stock schema looks like this(I removed some fields which are not related to this question to keep it simple):

```
const StockSchema = new Schema({
  qty: { type: Number, required: true },
  logs: [
    {
      qty: { type: Number, required: true },
      order: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'order', required: true },
    }
  ]
});
```

When an order takes place, there are scenarios where the `qty` has to be decremented from more than one `stock` document as a single stock does not have sufficient `qty`.

For an example lets say a product has two `stock` documents:

```
let stock1 = {
  qty: 3,
  logs: []
}

let stock2 = {
  qty: 5,
  logs: []
}
```

And we just received an order that wants 7 units.
So we first decrement 3 units from `stock1` and the remaining 4 from stock2.
The result should be:

```
let stock1 = {
  qty: 0,
  logs: [{ qty: 3, order: 'orderId' }]
};

let stock2 = {
  qty: 1,
  logs: [{ qty: 4, order: 'orderId' }]
};
```

Here is my code that does this:

```
let { qty } = order;
let stocks = await Stock.find({});
stocks= stocks.map(stock => {
  let change = 0;
  if (qty === 0) return stock;
  if (stock.qty >= qty) {
    change = qty;
    stock.qty -= qty;
    qty = 0;
  } else {
    change = stock.qty;
    qty -= stock.qty;
    stock.qty = 0;
  }
  stock.logs.push({ qty: change, order: orderId });
  return stock;
});
await Promise.all(stocks => stock.save()) //all the save occurs almost simultaneously, which is why Im expecting all or nothing issue is less of a problem.
```